# how to extract the first digits from a string with sub in r

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the first digits from a string.

```
s <- '100 xx-50 xx xxxx'
```

I can use str_extract from stringr

```
str_extract(s, '\\d+' )
[1] "100"
```

How to extract the string with sub in base r?
I tried:

```
sub('(\\d+)\\s.', '\\1', s)
[1] "100x-200 xx hello"
```

What did I do wrong? I could not figure it out. 
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s+.*", "", s)
#[1] "100"
```

---

In the OP's code, after the space (`\\s`) there is a `.` which means any character and there are more number of characters in the string, so it is not matching the characters in the string.  Instead, if we are going by the capture group route,

```
sub("^(\\d+)\\s.*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "100"
```

The `.*` implies zero or more characters and also note that the `^` is used to specify the start of the string so that it would not start from matching digits elsewhere in the string